# AbstractMethodError when using JPA/Hibernate with Jboss

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, jboss

I am using Jboss 4.3.2 GA, and i used the Hibernate and JPA jar files that come with Jboss. When i try to use my EntityManager i am getting the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/util/Map;)Ljavax/persistence/EntityManagerFactory;
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:83)
    at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:60)
    at com.netcertainty.server.model.lock.Client.main(Client.java:21)
```

Below is the code.

```
        EntityManager entitymanager = emfactory.createEntityManager( );
        entitymanager.getTransaction( ).begin( );

        entitymanager.persist( lockbean );
        entitymanager.getTransaction( ).commit( );

        entitymanager.close( );
        emfactory.close( );
```

Can anyone please help me. Thank you in advance.

Comment: AbstractMethodError => you are using inconsistent jars. Check through your jars with reference to the documentation of that software

Comment: Thanks for the help Billy. That fixed it..